# How to adjust left/right click regions in synaptics for clickpad

Tags: linux, arch-linux, synaptics-touchpad

I have an Arch Linux running in a Dell Vostro 5470, and the left click works in the left side of the clickpad, but the right side does nothing.

How can I enable the right click on the bottom-right side of the clickpad with synaptic?

**Edit:**

This is the output of `synclient -l`

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 136
    RightEdge               = 3284
    TopEdge                 = 120
    BottomEdge              = 2103
    FingerLow               = 1
    FingerHigh              = 1
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 179
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 81
    HorizScrollDelta        = 81
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0490436
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 0
    TapButton2              = 0
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 2
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 20
    VertHysteresis          = 20
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1710
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 1822
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: Is tapping with 2 Fingers a solution for you?

Comment: can you install `synclient` and add output of `synclient -l` to your question?

Comment: @davidbaumann Clicking with 2 fingers is what I'm doing now, but it would be nice if I had the single click.

Comment: @edvinas.me I've updated the question to include the output of the command